# x:Bind is not working with Listview and ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3, xbind

i want to read some data from sqlite and bind them to listview
this is my codes:

```
public ObservableCollection<ChapterProperty> Chapters { get; set; } = new();

using var db = new AlAnvarDBContext();
Chapters = new ObservableCollection<ChapterProperty>(await db.Chapters.ToListAsync());
```

and my xaml

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Chapters}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="tables:ChapterProperty">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

but my view is not updated and i cant see items.
where is wrong?

Comment: I have test above code, it works well, please check if you get correct items from sqlite

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT did you tested it in winui 3?

Comment: Yep, I tested within WInUI3 with fake item source `Chapters = new ObservableCollection<ChapterProperty>() { new ChapterProperty() { Name = "Test" } };` it could render listview item correctly

Comment: Does the following answer work? and any updates for this thread ?

Comment: @karma: Remove the setter from the property and update the existing collection instead of creating a new one. If you create a new collectiion, it's pointless to use an `ObservableCollection<T>` in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You bind to Chapters using a OneTime binding:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Chapters}">
```

then later replace Chapters:

```
Chapters = new ObservableCollection<ChapterProperty>(await db.Chapters.ToListAsync());
```

x:Bind is OneTime by default. Also unclear if Chapters is setup to dispatch PropertyChanged notifications. If it isn't, then the binding wouldn't update on a property change anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new collection at runtime like this:

```
Chapters = new ObservableCollection<ChapterProperty>(await db.Chapters.ToListAsync());
```

...you should modify the already existing collection:

```
var chapters = await db.Chapters.ToListAsync();
Chapters.Clear();
if (chapters != null)
foreach (var chapter in chapters)
     Chapers.Add(chapter);
```

Remove the setter to make sure that your initial collection is never replaced:

```
public ObservableCollection<ChapterProperty> Chapters { get; } = new();
```

If you replace the collection with another one each on each update, there is no reason to use an `ObservableCollection<T>` in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

You should use TemplateBinding instead

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/templatebinding-markup-extension

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Maybe some sample code would help.